# Changing deed on my house?

Tags: united-states, title

My house in Georgia USA is currently owned by me and my father in a "joint tenancy with survivorship" deed. My father wants to give his portion to his wife (my mother), but we would all like the final new deed to be a "joint tenancy with survivorship" between my mother and myself. I know that a quitclaim deed would allow my father to give his portion to my mother, but the resulting situation is a joint tenancy in common instead of a joint tenancy with survivorship rights between my mother and myself.

How would this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Owner A and Owner B together could deed the property to Owner A and Owner C as the new joint tenants with survivorship.